# Rotation matrix is not really symmetric (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, position, orientation

i am using the recoverPose() function in OpenCV but i don't get a symmetrical rotation matrix.
Shouldn't it return a symmetric rotation matrix?

My results are looking like:

```
R =  0.998585723955729,   0.02348487299776981,  0.04769709270061936;
    -0.02232705043463718, 0.9994464428542043,  -0.02466395517687959, 
    -0.04824991948907295, 0.02356413814160357,  0.9985572976364158;

t = -0.9982022017535427,  
     0.005659929033547541, 
     0.05966849769949602;
```

As you can see, the rotation matrix is not really symmetric and there is also something "wrong" with the signs of the values.

These are both images:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADpsa.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QduI6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3D rotation matrix is, in general, not symmetric. (Although some are, for example the identity matrix satisfies the properties of a rotation matrix and is symmetrical). Actually the general non-symmetry property is true for any number of dimensions, aside from the trivial 1D case.

You can see the general form of the 3D rotation matrix at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

(Note that the *determinant* of a rotation matrix is always 1).

Comment: So my rotation matrix is probably right and looks like a possible result of my two pictures?

Comment: Did you check the determinant? It looks pretty close to 1 to me.

Comment: yes.... it is 1.      
     


      I was just surprised, because my workmate said, that his rotation matrices were always symmetric.

Comment: @Mirnyy: You workmate needs a little bit of education. Start from the 2D case, and work up.